# Github - no write access to team's repo in organisation

Tags: git, github

On Github, I am a member of a team in an organisation with 'maintainer' status.

We have some repos under the team page, but I cannot `git push` (have write access?) to any of them.

Can someone please tell me what has to happen for me to have write access to the repos?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: `ERROR: Permission to [repo] denied to [me].
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`

Comment: As a maintainer, you have ability to add/remove team members of the team you are maintaining.  In order to be able to push, you need to be part of a team that has at least "write" access to the repository.

Answer (score 2):

**Checking your permissions**

If you are trying to clone a private repository but do not have permission to view the repository, you will receive this error.

Make sure that you have access to the repository in one of these ways:

- The owner of the repository
- A collaborator on the repository
- A member of a team that has access to the repository (if the
  repository belongs to an organization)

**Check your SSH access**

In rare circumstances, you may not have the proper SSH access to a repository.

You should ensure that the SSH key you are using is attached to your GitHub user account. You can check this by typing the following into the command line:

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
Hi username! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not
provide shell access.
```

**Check that the repository really exists**

If all else fails, make sure that the repository really exists on GitHub! If you're trying to push to a repository that doesn't exist, you'll get this error.